# Finding an interval $I \subset \{y \in \mathbb{R},\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{ix_n y}=f(y)\}$ such that $\int_{I}f(y)dy \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence of real numbers, $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function such that $\lambda(\{y \in \mathbb{R},\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{ix_n y}=f(y)\})>0.$

Is it possible to find an interval $I$ such that $\int_{I}f(y)dy \neq0 ?$

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $f(y)=0$ for $y\in \mathbb Q$ and else $f(y) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(ix_ny)$. Then for any $y\in\mathbb Q$ the property does not hold. But the set of irrational number has positive mass and has no inner points.

But when can this even be the case?

First of all $\exp$ is continuous. $\exp(ix_n y)$ moves on the complex unit circle, so that converges if and only if either $y=0$ or $x_n$ converges in a modulo $2\pi$ sense (so $(x_n)$ can be written as $(x_n^0)+(x_n^1)$ where $x_n^1$ converges against some $x$ and $x_n^0$ has only integral multiples of $2\pi$ as entries.

Then the question becomes: For what $y$ do we have $\exp(ixy) = f(y)$? If this set contains an interval then these two functions must be the same on that interval. But then
$$ \int_If\,dy = \int_I \exp(ixy)\, dy$$
If such an interval exists we can also find an Interval that this integral in not $0$.

EDIT: After you removed your limitations on $I$ the answer is yes. Basically: The set function $A \to \int_A f\,dy$ for measurable $A$ is uniquely given by it’s value on intervals. So if the integral is $0$ on all intervals it is also $0$ for all measurable sets.

But if $f$ is measurable then $\{f(y) = \exp(ixy)\}$ is measureable. Also if this set has positive mass we can find a subset so that the integral is not $0$.

Comment: I am a little confused, is it yes or no?

Comment: It’s no if $x_n$ does not converge in a modulo $2\pi$ sense. If it does then if $I$ is supposed to be a subset of that set that is exactly the case if $f(y)=\exp(ixy)$ on some interval for the limit $x$. If $I$ can be any interval it is generally yes.